# counting all sub categories whitin a category

Tags: php, mysql

I have database with following columns:

```
id, parent, name, description
```

The `id`has been set to auto incerement. I want to get total number of all the subcategories that are inisde the parent category (which has it's parent set to `0`) I also want this to be reccursive. What can be the fastes way of doing so?

I already wrote the following function but I can not test it at the moment:

```
function CountDeepSubCategories($parentID, $max = 0)
{
    global $_DB;

    $all = $all + $max;

    $q = $_DB->Query("SELECT id FROM category_cats WHERE parent = $parentID");
    $id = $_DB->GetResultValue($q, 0, 'id');

    $num = $_DB->GetResultNumber($q);       

    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
         CountDeepSubCategories($id, $all);
    }

    return $all;        
}
```

Comment: If there's not much records (like 100), but deep nesting (3+ levels) it's better to get all table and build a tree in `php`.

Comment: What exactly do you need? The question text suggests information (subcategories) but the code suggests an integer although your code will not do much as you are never using the return value of your recursive function.

Comment: Sorry it was not clear, I mean I need to know how many sub and sub-sub and.... categories that belong to the parent category (which has parent column as 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does every category have a parent? if that you can do "select count(*) from category_cats" :)

ok, for the second comment that you've posted, why dont you just add an insider query like this:

```
select cct.id,
    (select count(1) from category_cats where parent=cct.id) as subcount
from category_cats cct
```

i've not tested it but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the presentation from Bill Karwin at http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back (your problem is described at page 48). He explains pros and cons of your solution and offers three other ones and compares them against each other.

Comment: That presentation is actually based on [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book .. it's kinda mandatory IMHO.

Comment: I'm not affiliated to Bill Karwin, but I have to say that book was quite an eye opener. Very good and like you said a must have if you do work more often with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion seems like an elegant solution, it is however by far not the best-performer. You might consider storing you category tree as a [Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) which is quite an overhead when inserting new records, it, however, provides an advantage of getting the whole tree with one simple SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest (in SQL), but definitely not the easiest way, is to use preordered tree structure:

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/